# How to make an image header not show on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a header on my page with a block of text and an image next to it in a separate 'column' as per the following image:
[image: Header mock up]

How can I hide the image (the black part) of the header when I am on a mobile device? What would my CSS look like?

Comment: Using `@media` queries

Comment: Yes, but how do I actually hide it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries like as below :

```
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
   .black_part {
      display:none;
   } 
 }
```

Here maximum width I am assuming is 480px for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
/* iPhone (Portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px){
 .the_black_part{ display:none;}
}

/* iPhone (Landscape) ----------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){
 .the_black_part{ display:none;}    
}

/* iPad (Potrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px){
 .the_black_part{ display:none;}    
}
```

Comment: User is asking for mobile only, so first media query will be enough.

Comment: but when orientation is changes it comes in Landscape mode so 1st and 2nd is required

Comment: That mo will be for Tab not for mobile, As I think , mobile resolution we consider are 320x480.

Comment: According to bootstrap it is also required please follow the link to get more information "http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries"

Comment: I think both(first and second) are required for mobile devices B'coz first will cover up iphone (Portrait) and second will cover up iphone Landscape mode  all other smart phones